# Have Vader's eyebrows been retconned?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, star-wars-rebels

In Rebels Season Two's finale, *Twilight of the Apprentice*, it was revealed that Vader has eyebrows, which are missing in RotS & RotJ.

In the old days of the Holocron system, G-canon would override T-canon as in the aforementioned instance. In the present Disney system, however, I'm unconvinced the same approach applies. Further elaboration in the spoiler tag below because it's slightly off-topic, but it explains how I arrived at that belief. You can skip the elaboration if you want.

> The override approach allowed tolerance of any contradiction introduced, which is extremely confusing and unfriendly to newcomers to the universe. At one point, George Lucas decided to abandon his prior vision of Star Wars and overwrite it with a new vision. That was how the second, still-canon *Clone Wars* came into being. This was eventually formalised in Disney's official canon revamp. The new system worked on creating a singular, consistent world with content planned for commercial release decades into the future. That implies no override, and as such "all content are created equal". However, these material in George's and subsequently Disney's new vision have significant differences from even the movies before this vision change by George. One notable disconnect I felt when rewatching RotS recently is that the encounter between Grievous, Obi-Wan & Anakin feels too strongly like a first encounter as opposed to a meeting between familiar foes. Vader's eyebrows is just another difference. If we continue with the movie-over-TV approach to determining canonicity, most if not all Grievous-Kenobi-Skywalker scenes would have to be non-canon for the scene in RotS to make sense, so much so that the *Clone Wars* can hardly be worth calling.

As explained in the elaboration, I find it difficult to accept that the movies can still be considered to override everything else, such as TV shows, even if they are all Disney canon. My current headcanon, therefore, is that instead of "movies are more canon than television", it's now "the more recent work is canon". I can't prove this to be true, however, but it seems to be the more appropriate policy that doesn't contradict with what Disney retained as canon imo.

Considering that Rebels (which is canon) is produced more recently than RotS & RotJ (which are also canon), **can we say that Vader's eyebrows are retconned into existence?**

Comment: You're at the point where you need to know about dark vador's eyebrows? you should take a break :3

Comment: This is the silliest serious question I've seen in a while and I love it. +1 and hope the answer is just as silly.

Comment: Hey, you know what they said growing up: never stop asking questions ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if this really makes a difference or not, but are you specifically asking whether we should consider that Vader's eyebrows now canonically exist; or whether we can term their reappearance a retcon?

Comment: @Ixrec I think your wish has been realised ↓↓

Comment: "I find it difficult to accept that the movies can still be considered to override everything else, such as TV shows" -- Placing movies higher may cause some difficulties in understanding pieces of other things, but I would say it still should be done.  Star Wars has always had the movies be the central aspect that the series revolves around.  I never felt like the Clone Wars TV series was ever intended to usurp the importance of the movies.  If movies are what most people are familiar with, it makes sense for them to be what is treated as most canon.

Comment: I didn't see any mention of Vader's eyebrows in Rebels Season 2 or any Star Wars movie or show.

Comment: @TylerH it's not verbally mentioned. In the last ep, you can see his face. Comparing to his Clone Wars face, the model is almost the same. You can see the eyebrows there. Regardless of whether it is an out-of-universe mistake, the fact remains that the die has been cast - its existence must now be given an in-universe explanation.

Comment: ` [...] instead of "movies are more canon than television", it's now "the more recent work is canon".` Welcome to the mind of George Lucas

Comment: RotS (and the other prequels) should be considered non-canon for sanity's sake

Comment: You know, if you spent this much time on law working as a lawyer, you'd be rich.

Comment: @CCJ I won't say non-canon...a remake would be more appropriate.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Consider an acceptance on this one?

Answer (score 38):

Interestingly, Vader's eyebrows have apparently been a bone of contention at LucasFilm for decades. They were originally present in the theatrical release of RotJ

[image]

but were then digitally removed for the 2004 DVD release, presumably to line up with the injuries that we then saw in RotS

[image]

Since his eyebrows are present in Star Wars: Rebels but missing in Return of the Jedi (both of which are fully Disney canon), we can presume that they're not entirely missing and that he probably just removes them because they aren't as comfortable in his new helmet, bearing in mind that we just saw Ahsoka breaking the original one.

---

Lucasfilm's Pablo Hidalgo weighed in on this discussion with a [series](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/715576342578860033) [of](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/715581196453986304) [tweets](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/715582574589046784). Suffice to say, his responses are as helpful as ever.

> "To grow back eyebrows is a power only one has achieved. But if we
>   work together I know we can discover the secret." - Darth Sidious

and

> According to the doctrine of Darth Bane, Vader's eyebrows follow the
>   rule of two. #CANON.

Comment: “Broke the original” is probably the oddest sentence I've ever heard applied to eyebrows. Hidalgo’s tweets seem fairly unambiguous to me, though: they are definitely retconned back (or were, when he wrote the tweets).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In reality, this is probably just an animation oversight. They're only in frame for a few seconds, probably included by someone who was using a picture of [Haydn Christensen's face](http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/36100000/hayden-christensen-as-Anakin-Sywalker-image-hayden-christensen-as-anakin-sywalker-36182437-1024-768.jpg) as a guide

Comment: @Richard they were probably using the Anakin model from the Clone Wars CGI cartoon for reference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The newly-remastered version of the answer says "breaking the original one."  The usage of the word "one" causes the sentence to make even more odd to try to apply to the eyebrows.

Comment: @TOOGAM That just made me realise that it's the original helmet that Ahsoka broke, not his original eyebrows. Dammit!

Comment: When it comes to the power of Force Eyebrows, Darth Vader has succeeded where Sidious had failed. This is proof enough - Darth Vader has indeed become more powerful than Sidious or Yoda, and he is now the master of the two Sith Lords. That is why he sought out his son as the next apprentice. That is why Sidious sought to destroy Vader in counter to Vader's challenge for the title for Master of the Sith.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Hence the rule of two: one for each eyebrow.

Comment: Peace is a lie, there are only eyebrows.
Through passion, I gain eyebrows.
Through strength, I gain eyebrows.
Through power, I gain eyebrows.
Through eyebrows, my chains are broken.
The eyebrows shall free me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet One to see the light of day, the other to crave it.

Comment: I don't buy that Lucas removed Vader's brows for consistency reasons considering Anakin's injuries. Seems to me singed eyebrows would grow back. Also seems to me Lucas isn't terribly concerned with things making sense. My guess is they were removed due to an urge to meddle/tweak/perfect, and simple aesthetic feelings (modern reactions to body hair norms have changed), and/or a possible desire to make the man in the helmet look "lighter" and/or more similar to Hayden (i.e. having seen Hayden as young Anakin, Vader's original eyebrows might be thought to look unlike the same person).

Comment: This answer suggests the possibility that Vader removes his eyebrows, but it ignores the possibility that the eyebrows in *Rebels* could be fakes he wears and then ceases wearing, or that they were lost for some other reason (perhaps medication).

Comment: @jpmc26 - It seems less likely that he habitually wear fake eyebrows than that he removes them cosmetically.

Comment: @Richard sometimes you just want to look nice.  Even if you're the only Sith who knows.